# why this loop runs only one time and it dont ask again for new entrance?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
    //answer = input.nextLine();            
    do 
    {
        //input.hasNextLine();

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
        System.out.println("- Start a new Game (S)");
        System.out.println("- Exit (E)");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice: ");


            answer = input.next();
            if (answer.equals("s") || answer.equals("S")) 
                {
                    Hangman h1 = new Hangman();
                    h1.getWord();
                    h1.printData();
                    h1.CountTheLetters();
                    h1.GiveTheLetters();

                }
            input.hasNext();

    } while (answer.equals("e") || answer.equals("E"));

    System.out.println("Thank you for the game");
}
}
```

why this loop runs only one time and it dont ask again for new entrance? the menu in first time is appearing i enter s and i play the game. then i want to ask me again but it doesnt do it. why?
......

Comment: condition should be `!answer.equals("e") && !answer.equals("E")`

Comment: It's worth noting that you should also use "nextLine" and not next, or it won't work.Voting to close as "typo error"

Comment: now the menu is printed ok. but i get this--> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at Main.main(Main.java:34)

Comment: If it fixes your menu problem, close the question and start a new one with the new problem please.

Answer (score 2):

Because `answer` doesn't equal `"e"` nor `"E"`. Additionally, you need to check that the scanner still has elements to read.

Change the line to:

```
} while (input.hasNext() && !answer.equals("e") && !answer.equals("E"));
```

Comment: now the menu is printed ok. but i get this--> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:34)

Comment: You need to check if `input` still has elements to read. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: i done it. but now i play the game the menu it doesnt appeared and it prints Thank you for the game. So input.hasNext() returns false? why?